# Unselect all exposed filter options

Tags: 7, views

I added two term filters with operator **is one of**. I'm using better exposed filters to get them working with nested checkboxes and AJAX result updating. This works very well except one case:

I can't uncheck all checkboxes. The filters are optional and have no preselection at all. But after I selected one of the checkboxes I can't uncheck all of them again. If I uncheck the last checked chechbox it gets checked again after AJAX reload.

Is this s bug or did I miss something like to set/unset an option in view's configuration?

**UPDATE**

Okay to me it seems like a bug. If I untick the `Remember the last selection` option in the filter settings I can uncheck all options again.

Comment: I just tried your scenario, but couldn't reproduce the behaviour. Can you provide more information about exact settings?

Comment: @Volker Updated my question with the export of my view.